# SSL installed on Ubuntu 16 server will not route to 443 https

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl, ubuntu-16.04

I have an ubuntu server and I have installed the SSL certificate (3xs now after rekeying each time) and I still cannot get my server to route to https.

Here's my 000-default.conf file configuration...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.xxxx.me
        Redirect / https://www.xxxx.me
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName www.xxxx.me

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/xxxx/xxxx.me.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/xxxx/xxxx.me.key
        SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/xxxx/intermediate.crt

        ServerAdmin admin@xxxx.me
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        # I have also set the doc root to DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test with an index.php file in there to just test that https was working an it is not working...

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I have run this command:

> sudo a2enmod ssl

**Response is this:**

```
Considering dependency setenvif for ssl:
Module setenvif already enabled
Considering dependency mime for ssl:
Module mime already enabled
Considering dependency socache_shmcb for ssl:
Module socache_shmcb already enabled
Module ssl already enabled
```

I have restarted the server:

> sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: What do your error logs say? You may also need to add a <Directory "/var/www/html/"></Directory> tag with SSLRequireSSL inside it. I also add a trailing / after the Redirect line

Comment: *"I still cannot get my server to route to https"* - "still cannot get" is not an error description. What exactly is the problem: redirect not done as expected, SSL error messages in browser, or what? In other words: what did you try __exactly__ and how did you fail __in detail__ instead of just "I've tried some unspecified thing and it failed in an unspecified way".